# How do you resize FullCalendar window and cells in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

How does someone resize the calendar cells to their liking?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing shows you all the available options for controlling layout. Beyond that, it would be up to you to inspect the HTML of the part you want to change and come up with appropriate CSS. But be careful because that can sometimes have unpredictable results when the viewport is resized or nay affect the calendar's ability to display events in the correct place. Make sure you test any custom changes carefully.